# if $A\in O(n)$ and $\det A=-1$ then $A^2=I$ Any proof without using characteristics polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I am sorry for this simple and easy question.

> Is it true that If 
>   $A\in O(n)$ and $\det A=-1$ then $A^2=I$ ?

I know that $\det (A^2-I)=0$ (because $(A-A^t)^t=-(A-A^t)$) then its all eigenvalues are $1$. So it is similar to identity and hence $A^2=I$

1. Is my argument correct?
2. Any proof without using eigenvalues and characteristic polynomial?

Comment: $-I$ has all eigenvalues $-1$ and $\det(-I)=-1$.  Therefore, your conclusion about eigenvalues is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: You are right. How to fix it? at least in dim 2 or 2k?

Comment: For a $2\times 2$ matrix, the form of an element of $O(2)$ is very simple (and there's only two forms).  You can check this case directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=2$, the orthogonal group has elements of two forms:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
-\cos(\theta)&\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For matrices of the first type, the determinant is $1$, for matrices of the second type, the determinant is $-1$.

Squaring an element of the second type gives the identity, so the claim is true for $n=2$, by explicit calculation.

For $n\geq 3$, @AnginaSeng's answer can be extended via a block matrix.  If the matrix in that answer is $A$, then 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&I_{n-3}\end{bmatrix}
$$
has the same properties (its square is not $I_n$) and is in $O(n)$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\pmatrix{-1&0&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&-1&0}$$

Comment: Isn't it correct in dim 2?

Comment: Yes, the eigenvalues are then $1$ and $-1$ when $n=2$. @C.F.G